# SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

It shows Syntax Error: missing : after property id near `'<img src="loading.gif" />'`;`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#client").on("change", function() {
          var clientid=$("#client").val();

           $.blockUI(

           { 

            '<img src="loading.gif" />';
                timeout: 5000

           }); 

        $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php",
            data:"title="+clientid,
            success:function(data){
                 $('.blockUI').hide();
                 $("#result").html(data);
            }
        }); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `blockUI` script to:

```
$.blockUI({
     message: '<img src="loading.gif" />',
     timeout: 5000
});
```

Comment: Please refer this link https://co-de-snippet.blogspot.com/2022/07/javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after.html

Answer (score 0):

Property values of an object need to separated by commas, not semicolons. Your code should be:

```
message: '<img src="loading.gif" />',
timeout: 5000
```

For example, your `blockUI()` function should be called as follows:

```
$.blockUI({ 
    message: '<img src="loading.gif" />',
    timeout: 5000
});
```